# How to override Controller on Magento 1.9.x

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, overrides

I want to Override method setPathInfo on `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Coontroller/Request/Http.php` by my module (extension)

(not create file on local eg. `app/code/local/Mage/Core/Coontroller/Request/Http.php`)

Answer (score 2):

Since the class is directly called in several files (see `./code/core/Mage/GiftMessage/Model/Api.php` for example) you can not overwrite it in the normal Magento way via `config.xml`

Unfortunately this means there is no other option than to use a `local` rewrite.

However, depending on your case you could perhaps use observers to manipulate the behavior or value of the `setPath` method.